# How to limit activity access for a specific object and profile

Tags: profile, activities, access

I know it is possible to limit access to Activities for a Profile at the System Level:

[image]

Is it possible to only limit that access for a specific object? For instance, is there a way to only restrict a certain profile from viewing Activities on the Contact object but still view them on other objects?

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no way to get that level of granularity. If an object supports activities, and the profile allows activities, they will have access to those activities. If not, they will not.